# How to let the user to build a polygon on the open street map?

Tags: flutter, dynamic, polygon, openstreetmap

UPD: Done. Look at this beautiful polygon. [image]

UPD: In Flutter / openstreetmap, I want to let users draw a polygon by tapping a map and/or clicking a button. The polygon should be not filled. I need a very simple example just to get an idea of how it works.

The final task is:

I am making a flutter application that should give the user the ability to get information about markers located within a certain area on the map. I use osm. By pressing the button, the user initiates the construction of an arbitrary polygon, each corner of which is formed at the place of the next pressing of the button. When the construction of the polygon is completed, the objects inside the polygon are shown, the rest are hidden or not built. After that, the cycle ends by clearing the map.

I haven't found any solution for osm. I would appreciate any help. I don't have any code yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`flutter_map`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) library, I'm sure you can understand the documentation and how to set it up.

Then use `PolygonLayerOptions(polygons: [Polygon(points: polygonList)])` as a layer on top of the OSM layer. Then set up the list `polygonList` and use the `FlutterMap()`'s `onTap` callback to get the position at which the user tapped and add the `LatLng` to the `polygonList` list. There are multiple other configuration options within the `Polygon()` constructor, and those can be found through IntelliSense or similar. To have no fill, just set the color to transparent.

I use this method (or a very similar one) for my app which lets users download areas of map. The user taps the top left and bottom right of a rectangular area they want to download, by code calculates the top right and bottom left, and a polygon is drawn to show the user exactly where they tapped. Make sure to use `setState()` or similar.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I use flutter_map library. Right now I am trying to set a custom marker with a setState() and get its coordinates. Then I am going to collect coordinates of all my markers and try to make polygon using them. I expect to meet some difficulties, so, it would be great if you support me on this way in nearest Future 8-)

Comment: Sure, can't promise I'll be there, but I'll try to help!

Comment: Done! Wow! Many thanks)) Now I'll just make it transparent. It would be great if you recommend me a relevant reading (1 - 3 items). To be honest, I did not find a lot on the Internet regarding my issue.

Comment: Great to hear :)! To be honest, I couldn't find much online about it either, I just made it up as I went along for my app. There's a few issues caused (I'm assuming) by the lack of documentation: https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/issues/77. But that's it really. I just learnt that a polygon layer was there through IntelliSense. Anyway, glad I could help!