# In Flutter, how to add a marker on openstreetmap by tapping a screen or clicking a button?

Tags: flutter, openstreetmap, marker

It should be very simple, but I can't seem to find how to do it.

In Flutter / openstreetmap, I need to: (1) put a marker on the map by tapping a map and/or clicking a button; (2) connect two of these markers with a line(s).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to get road directions between two points or you want a straight line between two points?

Comment: I want a straight line. Finally, I want to let users build an arbitrary polygone and find markers inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** For adding markers:

```
List<Marker> markers = [];
```

Inside Build method:

```
          FlutterMap(
            mapController: _mapController,
            options: MapOptions(
                center: LatLng(41.238250, 69.342939),
                zoom: 9.6,
                onTap: (latlng) {
                  setState(() {
                    markers.add(
                      Marker(
                        width: 150.0,
                        height: 150.0,
                        point: latlng,
                        builder: (ctx) => const Icon(
                          Icons.location_on,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 35.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
                }),
            layers: [
              MarkerLayerOptions(
                markers: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) markers[i]
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

**2)** If you want to get directions between two points, you can use this service, it's free.  http://project-osrm.org

The link I am using for getting directions between two points.

[https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car?api_key=$OSRM_API_KEY&start=${origin.longitude},${origin.latitude}&end=${destination.longitude},${destination.latitude}](https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car?api_key=$OSRM_API_KEY&start=$%7Borigin.longitude%7D,$%7Borigin.latitude%7D&end=$%7Bdestination.longitude%7D,$%7Bdestination.latitude%7D)

It takes, API Key and starting point lat-long and ending point lat-long.

Response gives you multiple lat-long points, and if you give these points to polyLine parameter of map, it will draw you a road line between two points

***Let me know if you need any clarification on some part of my answer***

Comment: yes, List<Marker> markers = []; I updated answer

Comment: Yes, the (1) works! Fantastic! I go ahead. My task is to build a polygon / polyline and let users look at markers inside of it, as I wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374167/how-to-let-the-user-to-build-a-polygon-on-the-open-street-map

Comment: @kokserek I have no idea what to do with it yet/

Answer (score 2):

After the breaking changes in flutter_map 4.0.0 , the previous answer by @SardorbekR can be modified as follows:

```
FlutterMap(
            options: MapOptions(
              center: LatLng(50, 50),
              onTap: (tapPos, latlng) {
                setState(() {
                  markers.add(
                    Marker(
                      width: 100.0,
                      height: 100.0,
                      point: latlng,
                      builder: (ctx) => const Icon(
                        Icons.location_on,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        size: 35.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
              },
            ),
            children: [
              TileLayer(
                urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
              ),
              MarkerLayer(
                markers: [for (int i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) markers[i]],
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Note that this code is actually for flutter_map 3.0.0+. For migration information, see https://docs.fleaflet.dev/v/v3/migration/to-v3.0.0.